# How to subtract the current analog value from previous one

Tags: arduino-mega, power

I pretty new to the Arduino. I am working on project that find the power by reading your

Comment: Why would you want to subtract it? Do you maybe want to sum / integrate it over time to get total energy consumption?

Comment: I have this fourmal S=(V2-V1)/(P2-P1)

Comment: I have no idea what `S` is supposed to express here. But in the code you can take two measurements in predifened interval and then compute S.

Comment: S means the voltage sensitivity. Can you express what you said in code?

Comment: you do it by coding the sketch.

Comment: The formula should read P= U x I, V is for velocity and U is for voltage.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like the following :

```
int lastTime;

void loop(){
  int thisTime = analogRead(A1);
  int diff = thisTime - lastTime;
  lastTime = thisTime;
  Serial.println(diff);
}
```